# if Python doesn't support method overloading, then why does this method overload work while this other does not?

Tags: python, overloading

If Python does not support method overloading (besides *args and **kwargs or [PEP 3124](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3124/)), then why does this overload work?

```
# the sum from 1 to n
def sum(n):
    if n > 0:
        return n + sum(n - 1)
    else:
        return 0

print(sum(3))

# the sum from n to m, inclusive
def sum(n, m):
    if n <= m:
        return n + sum(n + 1, m)
    else:
        return 0

print(sum(3,5))
```

... while more baffling, this one does not:

```
# the sum of elements in an array
def sumArray(A):
    return sumArray(A, len(A)-1)

# a helper for the above
def sumArray(A, i):
    if i < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return A[i] + sumArray(A, i-1)

print(sumArray([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: what are you overloading?

Comment: Neither of them work. Try `print(sum(3))` instead of `print(sum(3,5))`, you'll get the same error than in the second case.

Comment: I get it - the mistake in my understanding derives from the order in which I used the `print` functions in the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function definitions are variable assignments. They create a function and assign it to the variable matching the name you used. You're seeing the ordinary effects of reassigning a variable.

```
def sum(n):
    ...
```

This assigns a function of 1 argument to the variable `sum`.

```
print(sum(3))
```

This uses the function assigned to that variable.

```
def sum(n, m):
    ...
```

This assigns a new function to the variable `sum`, replacing the first function.

```
print(sum(3,5))
```

This uses the new function. If you had tried to use the old function, you wouldn't find it.

---

```
# the sum of elements in an array
def sumArray(A):
    return sumArray(A, len(A)-1)

# a helper for the above
def sumArray(A, i):
    if i < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return A[i] + sumArray(A, i-1)

print(sumArray([1,2,3]))
```

This assigns a function to `sumArray`, then assigns a different function to `sumArray`, then tries to use the value from the first assignment. It finds the second function, and fails.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't overloading. You're hiding one thing behind another by using the same name for different objects. Try

```
sum = 42
```

and see how `print(sum(3, 5))` ceases to work.

Comment: If I set sum = 42, then I turn my method into an integer and it fails with `'int' object is not callable`. It's not the same error I get in the second example: `sumArray() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'`

Comment: Alright, I get it. Had I put the two print functions one after the other instead of inline as I did, I would have got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you define function and use it, then overwrite it with another, and use the new one, just like with regular variables:

```
a = 1
print(a)

a = 2
print(a)
```